# EMR in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Getting the below error when I try to deploy EMR in private subnet through data pipeline.
Invalid Field: 'ServiceAccessSecurityGroup'

It's working fine when I launch the EMR using AWS template. Anyone encountered similar issue and resolved it?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9518 and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-man-sec-groups.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServiceAccessSecurityGroup` isn't a supported field on `EmrCluster` Resource object on Data Pipelines. So, essentially, using Data Pipelines Resource  objects, you cannot spin up an EMR cluster on Private subnet. 
**https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emrcluster.html**